# Windows PowerShell JSON to CSV "System.Object[]" issues

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I've been struggling for 3 days trying to convert a JSON file to a CSV.  Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with powershell and any help would be appreciated.  Here is the JSON String:

```json
{"inputFile": [["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10"], ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"], ["K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"]]}
```

Command lines that I've tried:

```
ConvertFrom-JSON (Get-Content 'path.json' -Raw) |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Set-Content 'path.csv'

Get-Content 'path.json' -Raw |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select -Expand inputFile |
    ForEach {$_.inputFile = $_.inputFile -join ' '$_} |
    Export-Csv 'path.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Nothing...

I am hoping to get a CSV file with:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, etc.
A,B,C,etc.
```

What combination of commands can I use to do this?

Comment: Your JSON is an array of arrays. Do you control the creation of the JSON?

Answer (score 3):

`Export-Csv` expects a list of objects as input. The properties of the objects (identified by the properties of the first object) are exported as the columns of the CSV. For the cmdlet to work the way you expect your input data would have to look like this:

```json
{
    "inputFile": [
        {
            "Column1": "A",
            "Column2": "B",
            ...
        },
        {
            "Column1": "K",
            "Column2": "L",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

In your case you have each row in a separate array, so it's easier to just join those arrays and then write the output as a text file:

```bsh
Get-Content 'path.json' -Raw |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -Expand inputFile |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -join ',' } |
    Set-Content 'path.csv'
```

Answer (score -1):

So this is about as convoluted as it gets, and I hope someone else answers. But this worked for me. Without changing the data in your JSON I'm not sure what else to tell you.

```
$y = ''
$x = '{"inputFile": [["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10"], ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"], ["K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"]]}'
($x | ConvertFrom-JSON).inputfile | % {$_ | %{$y += ($_ + "`t")}; $y+="`n"}
$y | out-file x.csv
```

It's basically just text manipulation. I created it as tab delimited since that was default with excel, but you can change it to anything else.